# UIBarButtonItem tint modification on iPad Pro 10.5 running IOS 11.2.5

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, tint

After updating my iPad Pro 10.5 to IOS 11.2.6, the UIBarButtonItem tint modification does not respond anymore. It works fine on the iPhone IOS 11.2.5 with the same IOS version. It also works fine on the iPad Pro 10.5 simulator running iOS 11.2

Has anyone noticed the same thing?.

I suppose if it was a coding error, other devices and simulators would reproduce the same issue.

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var onOffButton: UIBarButtonItem!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 }


@IBAction func buttonPush(_ sender: Any) {
    onOffButton.tintColor = UIColor.orange
}
```

}

Can anyone confirm this issue please?

Comment: I have found that if you set "Accessibility/Bold Text" On, UIBatButtonITem.Tint stops working. Any solution to this?

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89337